# Django: Setting the from address on an email

Tags: python, django, smtp

I'd like for my users to be able to enter their `email-address` and `message` and then send the email with the 'from address' being their own email-address. Currently the `EMAIL_HOST` is set on our own domain and the emails arrives when it is sent with a "from address" equal to our `HOST_USER`, but not if it is anything else. Is this possible?

Our settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp02.hostnet.nl'  
EMAIL_PORT = 587  
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True  
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "xxx"  
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "xxx"  
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you allow your users to set the from addresss, you may find that your emails are blocked by anti-spam measures.

A better approach would be to use an email address you control as the from address, and set the `reply_to` header on your email. Then, when the recipients click 'reply', the reply will go to the user's from address.

```
email = EmailMessage(
    'Hello',
    'Body goes here',
    'your-email-address@example.com',  # from address
    ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'], # recipients
    reply_to=[user_from_address],  # reply to address set by your user
)
email.send()
```